# Writing Diesel CRUD operations for generic types

Tags: rust, crud, rust-diesel

I am trying to write a Rust crate which removes some boilerplate code from the user when creating simple CRUD operations with [Diesel](http://diesel.rs/)

For instance, if you have a Diesel `Insertable` like this one:

```rust
#[derive(Insertable)]
#[table_name = "users"]
pub struct UserCreate<'a> {
    pub email: String,
    pub hash: &'a [u8],
    pub first_name: Option<String>,
    pub family_name: Option<String>,
}
```

I want the crate user to just write `create<UserCreate>(model, pool)`, to insert the struct fields into a database row.

To do so, I've written the following function signature (simplified for example):

```rust
fn create<'a, C: 'a>(model: C, pool: DBPool)
where
    C: diesel::Identifiable,
    &'a C: diesel::Insertable<C::Table>,
{
    let conn = pool.get().unwrap();
    diesel::insert_into(C::table())
        .values(&model)
        .execute(&conn);
}
```

The issue is that the compiler complains about some missing trait bounds for `C` and `&C` at `.execute(&conn)` and I am not quite sure how to place them in the `where` clause, there may be also a simpler way of doing this which I am not aware of. Any hint is very welcome!

Compiler output:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table as diesel::QuerySource>::FromClause: diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<_>` is not satisfied
  --> database/src/users/models.rs:46:10
   |
46 |         .execute(&conn);
   |          ^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<_>` is not implemented for `<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table as diesel::QuerySource>::FromClause`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'a T as diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<DB>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<_>` for `diesel::query_builder::InsertStatement<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table, <&C as diesel::Insertable<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table>>::Values>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::load_dsl::ExecuteDsl<_, _>` for `diesel::query_builder::InsertStatement<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table, <&C as diesel::Insertable<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table>>::Values>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `<&C as diesel::Insertable<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table>>::Values: diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<_>` is not satisfied
  --> database/src/users/models.rs:46:10
   |
46 |         .execute(&conn);
   |          ^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<_>` is not implemented for `<&C as diesel::Insertable<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table>>::Values`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'a T as diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<DB>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<_>` for `diesel::query_builder::InsertStatement<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table, <&C as diesel::Insertable<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table>>::Values>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::load_dsl::ExecuteDsl<_, _>` for `diesel::query_builder::InsertStatement<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table, <&C as diesel::Insertable<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table>>::Values>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `<&C as diesel::Insertable<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table>>::Values: diesel::insertable::CanInsertInSingleQuery<_>` is not satisfied
  --> database/src/users/models.rs:46:10
   |
46 |         .execute(&conn);
   |          ^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::insertable::CanInsertInSingleQuery<_>` is not implemented for `<&C as diesel::Insertable<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table>>::Values`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'a T as diesel::insertable::CanInsertInSingleQuery<DB>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<_>` for `diesel::query_builder::InsertStatement<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table, <&C as diesel::Insertable<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table>>::Values>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::load_dsl::ExecuteDsl<_, _>` for `diesel::query_builder::InsertStatement<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table, <&C as diesel::Insertable<<C as diesel::associations::HasTable>::Table>>::Values>`

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally solved by defining the following trait bounds!

```rust
fn create<C, T>(model: C, pool: DBPool)
where
    T: diesel::associations::HasTable,
    <T::Table as diesel::QuerySource>::FromClause:
        diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<diesel::pg::Pg>,
    C: diesel::Insertable<T::Table>,
    C::Values: diesel::insertable::CanInsertInSingleQuery<diesel::pg::Pg>
        + diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<diesel::pg::Pg>,
{
    let conn = pool.get().unwrap();

    diesel::insert_into(T::table())
        .values(model)
        .execute(&conn);
}

create::<UserCreate, users::table>(user, pool);
```

Basically, you need a pair of extra bounds for the `Table` and the `Insertable`. It would be nice if it was possible to get the table directly from the `Insertable`, to avoid using another type in the function definition, but I can work with that :)

Comment: hi if i want to replace `excute` with `get_result` what the trait i need to implement. THank @codearm

Comment: see this answer for a less verbose example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63759354/2650622

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is correct but can be made less verbose by using higher bounds

```
use diesel::query_builder::{InsertStatement};
use diesel::query_dsl::methods::{ExecuteDsl};

pub fn insert_into_table<T, M>(conn: &Pgconnection, table: T, records: M)
where
    T: Table,
    M: diesel::Insertable<T>,
    InsertStatement<T, M::Values>: ExecuteDsl<PgConnection>,
{
    diesel::insert_into(table)
        .values(records)
        .execute(conn);
}
```